# Regular expression for validating year starting from 2020

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a regular expression to validate year starting from 2020.

The below is the regular expression I wrote,

```
^(20-99)(20-99)$
```

It doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point out where did I get it wrong?

Comment: Your second group will only accept values 20-99 and you need it to accept 00-99.  For example 3000.

Comment: Your regex only accepts only one string: `"20-9920-99"`. Before using a tool, try to read a bit about it: I don't think you've spent much time learning. If you did, you'd probably come to the conclusion that regex is not the right tool in your case.

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks, I realized my error after looking at JLundberg comment. I must admit regex is not my forte and there is better way of doing this using comparison operator, but due to requirement constraint, I have to use regex.

Comment: More detail needed. ANY year beyond 2020? Like 10556? Abbreviations OK, like '20 or 55? Commas in 5 digit years? 2021AD OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions don't take ranges like that. You'll want to do something like:

```
if( year >= 2020 )
  presto
```

I'm being flippant because you're trying to use a regular expression where you can just use a straight-forward comparison. If you have a string, convert the string into an integer first (if you even need to do that with Python). Otherwise, you're going to have some really ugly regular expression that's hard to maintain.

**Edit:** If you're really keen on using a regular expression (or three), your problem can be broken up into three regular expressions: `^20[2-9]\d$`, `^2[1-9]\d\d$`, `^[3-9]\d{3}$` for four-character years. You could combine these into `^(20[2-9]\d|2[1-9]\d\d|[3-9]\d{3})$`.

But note that the regular expression is a) ugly as hell, and b) only accepts years up to 9999. You can mitigate this with judicious use of the `+`, so something like:

```
^(20[2-9]\d+|2[1-9]\d{2,}|[3-9]\d{3,})$
```

...could work.

But I hope you'll find that just doing `year >= 2020` is a lot better.

**Edit 2:** Hell, that regex is wrong for years greater than 9999. You'll probably want to use:

```
^(20[2-9]\d|2[1-9]\d{2}|[3-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4,})$
```

And that still doesn't work if you enter a year like `03852`.

Comment: Thanks. But due to some requirement constraint, I may not use comparison operator.

Comment: @Ted please post what you are trying to do so we can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps OP is... I don't know... writing a PEG where he needs to disambiguate years before and after 2020?

Comment: @CanSpice Thank you, it sure look ugly with the regex when it can simply be done using comparison operator and the usual if-then-else. Can't thank you enough for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain about python but w.r.t. to regex it doesn't work like you are thinking...ranges are for a single character. So if for some reason you *must* have a regexp (ie: some sort of regexp data-filled validation engine):

```
^20[2-9][0-9]|[2-9][1-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

Any number from 2020-2099 or 2100-9999.

Comment: Can't see how this catches the year 3000 (just around the corner).

Comment: And you can golf that a little by using `\d` for `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a significantly shorter regex that does what you want:

```
^(?![01]|20[01])\d{4}$
```

Validation:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^(?![01]|20[01])\d{4}$')
>>> all(regex.match(str(x)) if x >= 2020 else not regex.match(str(x)) for x in xrange(10000))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want from 2023 here is one I done

```
^20([2-9][3-9]|[3-9][0-9])|2100$
```

Range is 2023 - 2100

just change the first [3-9] to whatever year you are on. So next year would be [4-9] and so on

```
^20([2-9][4-9]|[3-9][0-9])|2100$
```

Range is 2024 - 2100 and so on keep changing the [4-9] for the next year etc..

To expand it even further include Months as
YYYY/MM OR YYYY-MM OR YYYY MM

I have this:

```
^(20([2-9][3-9]|[3-9][0-9])|2100)[\s\/-](0[1-9]|1[0-2])$
```